# how to distribute a GWT project to two different developer

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am developing a GWT project in which i need a front end developer to handle all the front end things and a back end developer to look all the coding side , but i don't want a front end developer to see my coding stuff and don't want a back end developer to see my view .

Is it possible in any way in GWT?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be pretty easy if you structure the project properly. You should have three packages: `client`, `server` and `shared`.

`shared` should contain RPC service, service async and DTO (or model) classes.

Frontend guy needs `client`, `shared` and a mock version of `server`.

Backend guy needs `server`, `shared` and a mock version of `client`.

So, to keep them in the dark you need to create mock versions of `client` and `shared` that need to be updated only when `shared` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the only thing the server shares with the client is the RemoteServiceImpl. As long as you share the same XXXImpl with method stubs, you need not see each other's code at all.